# A custom "letter" in text mode

Tags: accents, characters, text-mode

I am trying to typeset a letter `x` (in both lower- and uppercase) that has a small circle overlaid exactly onto the (perceived) middle of the character.  My current best effort is `x\llap{$\circ$}`, but not only is the resulting circle somewhat bigger than I want, it is visibly not quite centered on the `x`.

I am using XeLaTeX, if it helps.  I have tried looking for unicode combining characters that would do what I want, but the only two candidates I saw (`U+208D` "COMBINING RING OVERLAY" and `U+20DD` "COMBINING ENCLOSING CIRCLE") were both very large, and also shared the failure of centering.

Ideally, I would be able to have a simple command that produces this "custom character", because I will need to use it many times.

EDIT:  I've decided to use the `stackengine`-based solution, but all the options look good.  Thanks!

EDIT 2:  I've switched to the `tikz`-based solution, because it generalizes much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `tikz`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\circledx}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (a) {x};
  \draw (a.center) circle (0.15ex);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\circledX}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (a) {X};
  \draw (a.center) circle (0.2ex);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
  \circledx and \circledX
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There is a special command for that in the [`stackengine`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stackengine) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\color{red}$\scriptstyle\circ$}{\color{ForestGreen}$x$} \quad \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\color{red}$\scriptstyle\circ$}{\color{ForestGreen}x}

\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\color{red}$\scriptscriptstyle\circ$}{\color{ForestGreen}$x$}\quad \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\color{red}$\scriptscriptstyle\circ$}{\color{ForestGreen}X}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool!  This seems to be just as good as the other options.

Answer (score 3):

Not with `tikz`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\def\cx
  {{\ooalign{x\cr
    \hidewidth\raisebox{.2ex}{$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle\circ$}\kern.01em \hidewidth\cr}}}
\def\cX
  {{\ooalign{X\cr
    \hidewidth\raisebox{.4ex}{$\m@th\scriptstyle\circ$}\kern.01em \hidewidth\cr}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \cx\ and \cX
\end{document}
```

[image]

This code places the original ring accent (which is smaller in Computer Modern and you might prefer).

```
\makeatletter
\def\cx
  {{\ooalign{x\cr
    \hidewidth\raisebox{-.95ex}{\r{}}\hidewidth\cr}}}
\def\cX
  {{\ooalign{X\cr
    \hidewidth\raisebox{-.62ex}{\r{}}\kern.01em \hidewidth\cr}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This is also good, although the circle is a little big still; nonetheless, I'll have to keep this approach in mind.

Comment: You can always scale it down `\scalebox{.5}{..}`. In any case, if it's too small, is it noticeable? It looks more like a dot/bullet than a circle.

Comment: I'm using a font with very thin lines, so it remains visibly a circle at tiny proportions.  Thanks for `\scalebox`, though!

Comment: I added another alternative with original ring accent `\r{..}`. The basic idea is that you can use whatever symbol you want.