# Extending TikZ fadings to the very ends of a character

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, transparency, shading

I'm having a problem with the "custom letter" that I've already asked [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244225/a-custom-letter-in-text-mode) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271535/using-a-macro-inside-a-tikz-coordinate-calculation) about. The following MWE illustrates the issue:

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{accsupp,xcolor,fontspec,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\pgfkeys{/SS/xX/thickness/.initial=0.125ex,/SS/xX/thickness/.value required}
\pgfkeys{/SS/xX/shift/.initial={(0ex,0ex)},/SS/xX/shift/.value required}
\pgfkeys{/SS/xX/size/.initial=0.25ex,/SS/xX/size/.value required}
\newcommand*\nulx[1][]{\BeginAccSupp{method=escape,unicode,ActualText={x⃘}}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=auto]\pgfqkeys{/SS/xX}{#1}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=x circle fading,outer sep=auto]
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,white,fill=white] (letter) {x};
\draw[line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/SS/xX/thickness},white,fill=black] (0,0) circle (\pgfkeysvalueof{/SS/xX/size});
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{scope}[outer sep=auto]
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,scope fading=x circle fading,fit fading=false,fading transform={shift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/SS/xX/shift}}] (letter) {x};
\draw[line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/SS/xX/thickness},.] let \p{shift} = \pgfkeysvalueof{/SS/xX/shift} in ($ (letter.center) + (\x{shift},\y{shift}) $) circle (\pgfkeysvalueof{/SS/xX/size});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\EndAccSupp{}}
\begin{document}
\textit{x \nulx}
\end{document}
```

[image: A comparison of <code>x</code> and <code>\nulx</code>.]

As you can see, the "custom letter" has its ends "cut off," which looks terrible and is generally undesirable.  How can I make TikZ recognize the full extent of the letter, rather than just the central portion?

Comment: Is it `inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt` that causes this?

Comment: It appears so, but in the absence of that the letter doesn't lie within the textual line.

Comment: This seems to depend on the viewer:  Adobe Reader, qpdfview, and Okular show the problem, but mupdf, zathura, apvlv, and atril do not, while xpdf shows only half of the problem.

Comment: @Thérèse "Half the problem"?

Comment: Yes, the figure appears cut off on one side only.

Comment: It seems to me as if `x` is protruding out of its bounding box on both sides.  That is to say, there is nothing you can do about it except from enlarging the clipping box, because the glyph doesn't “know” about shapes outside of its bounding box.

Comment: Here is a [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WvzSd.png) to show the glyph boundaries.

Comment: @HenriMenke I see.  In that case, is there any way to enlarge the clipping box without also enlarging the space that TeX "thinks" the letter takes up?

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame Replace `inner sep` by `inner xsep` and `inner ysep` , leave `inner ysep=0pt` and raise `inner xsep` to your liking.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks!  That works beautifully; if you made that an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: @HenriMenke You should make your comment an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>[[My comment as an answer]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285021/extending-tikz-fadings-to-the-very-ends-of-a-character?noredirect=1#comment688454_285021)</sup>

Replace `inner sep` by `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`, leave `inner ysep=0pt` and raise `inner xsep` to your liking.